# String to JSON in Poco/JSON or rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries, rapidjson

i want to convert the following std::string message into a json object so that I can easily to traverse the object and get the key/value pair as needed.

I prefer to use either rapidjson or Poco::JSON

```
std::string request;
std::cout << request << std::endl;

This is the output of request:    {"USER_ID":"1","Exchange":"NASDAQ","ActionType":"BUY","OrderType":"MARKET","Quantity":"100","TimeInForce":"GTC"}
```

Comment: Or convert your string directly into normal C++ structure. https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example1.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the string to document, then parse